# ckfinder php 2.6.2 settings view, display, sorting doesn't working

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, ckeditor, ckfinder

the example

[image]

Functions are not working. someone with the same problem? any suggestion? thanks

Comment: I am having this problem with ckfinder 2.1 as well, but we are not using php we are using CFM. It doesn't seem like a server side issue to me, because if you change the default view behaviour to list view, with something like this: config.defaultViewType = 'list';   than the list view works fine.  It must be some logic which incorporates the date o something in the front-end code of finder 2.x

Comment: open the file ckfinder.js, and edit this line ... {document.cookie=l+'='+m+(!n?'; expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2016 01:00:00 UTC; path=/':'');} to {document.cookie=l+'='+m+(!n?'; expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2038 01:00:00 UTC; path=/':'');}

Answer (score 5):

Open the file `ckfinder.js` and edit this line:

```
{document.cookie=l+'='+m+(!n?'; expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2016 01:00:00 UTC; path=/':'');}
```

to:

```
{document.cookie=l+'='+m+(!n?'; expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2038 01:00:00 UTC; path=/':'');}
```

Comment: Thank you. Our team would have spent days trying to figure out the issue and would have probably never found the solution. You are our hero

Answer (score 5):

There was an unfortunate bug in CKFinder, which was left unattended. We do our best to provide reliable software, but even such weird bugs in software sometimes happen.

Once we found out that the bug exists in the setCookie function we released CKFinder 2.6.2.1 for anyone willing to take this occasion to update CKFinder 2.x to the latest stable version which is free of this bug.

Also, considering that the issue was definitely our fault, we fixed all previous packages of CKFinder for ASP/ASP.NET/ColdFusion/PHP starting from version 2.0 to make the patch process as smooth as possible. So anyone using an older version of CKFinder (e.g. 2.3), who is willing to simply get rid of the bug, may download CKFinder 2.3 again and just replace the invalid `ckfinder.js` file (and refresh browser cache). This step can be performed by all clients, even the one with expired license. Again, this issue was unintentional and we did our best to fix all packages as soon as we realised what is the source of the issue. Also today we'll send an email to all registered users asking to download a fixed version of CKFinder, knowing that some of them might not notice that users are no longer able to use all features of CKFinder.

CKFinder for Java users should upgrade to 2.6.2.1, customers with expired license that do not want to update to the latest stable version may [contact us](http://cksource.com/contact) in order to get a fixed package without the need to update their license.