# CKFinder does not display in text listing view, only image view

Tags: listview, columnsorting

CKFinder does not display in text listing view, only image view, and the sorting does not work. This is a new occurrence this morning with an existing install.

Answer (score 0):

[ckfinder php 2.6.2 settings view, display, sorting doesn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903515/ckfinder-php-2-6-2-settings-view-display-sorting-doesnt-working)

In ckfinder.js there's an expiration date

```
expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2016 01:00:00 UTC;
```

It should be replacing with a future date.